# Select all rows with multiple occurrences - on same day

Tags: mysql

I have a single MySQL table with the name 'checkins' and 4 columns.

```
  id | userIDFK |    checkin_datetime   | shopId
 ------------------------------------------------
  1  |    1     |  2018-01-18 09:44:00  |   3
  2  |    2     |  2018-01-18 10:32:00  |   3
  3  |    3     |  2018-01-18 11:19:00  |   3
  4  |    1     |  2018-01-18 17:57:00  |   3
  5  |    1     |  2018-01-18 16:31:00  |   1
  6  |    1     |  2018-01-19 08:31:00  |   3
```

Basically I want to find rows where users have checked-in more than once (>=2) on the same day and the same shop. So for instance if a user checks-in as in rows with ids 1 and 4 (same user, same day, same shop), the query should return a hit with the the entire rows (id, userIDFK, checkin_datetime, shopId). Hope this makes sense.

I already tried using

```
 SELECT id, userIDFK, checkin_datetime, shopId
 FROM (
    SELECT * FROM 'checkins' WHERE COUNT(userIDFK)>=2 AND COUNT(shopId)>=2
 )
```

The same day part I have no clew how to do it, and I know this query is way off, but this is the best I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grouping by userId checkin_date and shopID

```
SELECT userIDFK, checkin_datetime, shopId,COUNT(SHOPiD)
FROM checkins
GROUP BY userIDFK, DATE(checkin_datetime), shopId
HAVING COUNT(SHOPID)>1
```

**EDIT**

You can include a subquery to get all lines:

```
select b.id,b.userIDFK, b.checkin_datetime, b.shopId
from checkins b
where (SELECT COUNT(SHOPiD)
       FROM checkins a
       where a.userIDFK=b.userIDFK and date(a.checkin_datetime)=date(b.checkin_datetime) and  a.shopId=b.a.shopId
       GROUP BY userIDFK, DATE(checkin_datetime), shopId)>1
```

Comment: This is almost it, but it only returns 1 row pr. group, how can it return all rows for each group?

Answer (score 1):

`GROUPBY` can be used to get the multiple occurrences.

```
SELECT id, userIDFK, checkin_datetime, shopId
FROM checkins 
GROUP BY userIDFK, DATE(checkin_datetime), shopId 
HAVING count(id) > 1;
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

Using inner join you can achieve it. Here is the query:

```
SELECT c1.* FROM checkins c1 INNER JOIN checkins c2 
ON c1.userIDFK = c2.userIDFK 
AND date(c1.checkin_datetime) = date(c2.checkin_datetime) 
AND c1.shopId = c2.shopId 
AND c1.id != c2.id
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is almost it, but it only returns 1 row pr. group, how can it return all rows for each group?

Comment: Added the query to return all the multiple occurrence rows. Let me know if anything.